# Analyze additions and subtractions to/from a data set

Tags: python, sql, excel, max, min

I have a data set in the following form:

```
Product    |    Date
123        |    2019-01-01
456        |    2019-01-01
123        |    2019-01-02
123        |    2019-01-03
456        |    2019-01-03
123        |    2019-01-04
456        |    2019-01-04
789        |    2019-01-04
```

This is just a simplified version. The full set has ~300 products and four months of data. I want to understand how the product set changed over time. It's obviously easy to calculate the count per day and see that I lost one product on Jan 2nd and gained one on Jan4th, but then I don't know what product it was.

Is there a more systematic way of going about this? Ideally the output would show me a list of days and what products dropped out / were added that day, i.e.:

```
Date        |   Product   |   Type
2019-01-02  |   456       |   Out
2019-01-03  |   456       |   In
2019-01-04  |   789       |   In
```

I thought about min(date), max(date) by product before, but products can drop and be added repeatedly and I wouldn't capture this back and forth this way.

Available environments are Python, SQL, and Excel.

Thanks

Comment: "...see that I lost one product on Jan 2nd and gained one on Jan4th..." -- I can't see that at all from the sample data. You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your question to clarify it. Including what you've tried so far and the expected outcome would also be useful.

Comment: Product 456 was not in the data set on Jan 2nd (came back one day later), Product 789 wasn't in the data set to begin with and showed up on Jan 4th for the first time

Answer (score 0):

To generate the list of missing entries, you could make a cartesian product of `product`s and `date`s using `CROSS JOIN`, and use it to detect the gaps in the table with a `LEFT JOIN` anti-pattern, like:

```
SELECT p.product, d.date
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT product FROM mytable) p
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date from mytable) d
    LEFT JOIN mytable t ON t.product = p.product AND t.date = d.date
WHERE t.product IS NULL
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dz442XWb59hnBnfT7jRgRf/0)**:

```
| product | date       |
| ------- | ---------- |
| 789     | 2019-01-01 |
| 456     | 2019-01-02 |
| 789     | 2019-01-02 |
| 789     | 2019-01-03 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution. Group the products by dates and convert them to sets. Then, calculate running set differences both ways.

```
as_set = df.groupby('Date')['Product'].apply(set)
changes = pd.concat([as_set - as_set.shift(),
                     as_set.shift() - as_set], axis=1).dropna()
changes.columns = "In", "Out"
#               In    Out
#Date                    
#2019-01-02     {}  {456}
#2019-01-03  {456}     {}
#2019-01-04  {789}     {}
```

You can further eliminate null entries:

```
#import numpy as np
#changes.replace(set(), np.nan).stack()
#Date           
#2019-01-02  Out    {456}
#2019-01-03  In     {456}
#2019-01-04  In     {789}
```